# Strange pattern matching behaviour with AnyRef

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

```
def test1(a: Any) = a match {
  case x: AnyRef => "AnyRef"
  case _ => "None of the above"
}

def test2(a: Any) = a match {
  case x: Double if x > 2 => "Double > 2"
  case x: AnyRef => "AnyRef"
  case _ => "None of the above"
}
```

Please can someone explain why in the following, the first case `1.0` matches on `AnyRef`, but in the second it doesn't. (Scala 2.9.0-1)

```
scala> test1(1.0)
res28: java.lang.String = AnyRef

scala> test2(1.0)
res29: java.lang.String = None of the above
```

---

edit - **Scala 2.10 update Jan 2013**: the new pattern matcher fixes this behaviour (or at least, makes it consistent) and the method `test2` now returns "AnyRef" as for `test1`.

Comment: when compiled, what's generated is if(a instanceof Double) { if(a > 2) { return "Double > 2"} else { return "None of the Above" } } else { if(a instanceof Object) { return "AnyRef"} else {return "None of the Above"}} . So, unless someone find something in the scala specification, I think it's scala compiler bug

Comment: `1.0` is a `Double` which is a subtype of `Any` but not of `AnyRef` in contrast to `java.lang.Double`. So I even wonder why `1.0` matches `AnyRef` in `test1`.

Comment: I deleted my answer. It is not a bug -- I did not notice you were matching against `AnyRef`. Rex Kerr is correct.

Comment: @PeterSchmitz: according to the spec, you're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `Any` is actually just an `Object`.  Having `Double` there is a convenient fiction--it's actually `java.lang.Double` which is autounboxed for you in the match statement.  Unfortunately, there is no way for Scala to tell if it finds a `java.lang.Double` if it is supposed to be interpreted as a `Double` or as a `java.lang.Double`--in the latter case, the `AnyRef` should catch it.  So it does.  But if you specifically *ask* for a `Double`, it knows it is supposed to unbox, and then the `AnyRef` case need not be checked.  (And, in fact, if you intended it to be a `java.lang.Double`, it will unbox that too--it can't tell the difference.)

Whether this is *ideal* behavior is debatable, but it is logical.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why `1.0` is matched in `test1`.

Comment: @RexKerr I am not sure I still buy it.  "in the latter case, the AnyRef should catch it." except that it doesn't since "None of the Above" is printed.  I also assume that a match case's result should equal it's composing partial functions...

`val x:PartialFunction[Any, String] = {case x:Double if x > 2 => "Double > 2"}
val y:PartialFunction[Any, String] = {case x:AnyRef => "AnyRef"}
val z:PartialFunction[Any, String] = {case _ => "None of the Above"}
println(test2(1.0)) // => None of the Above
val chain = x orElse y orElse z
println(chain(1.0)) // => AnyRef`

Comment: @DanielHinojosa - As I said, I'm not sure that this is ideal: `AnyRef` should catch it _unless you specify you want `Double`_.  One could argue that the guard on `Double` should indicate that you only want _those_ `Double`s to be considered as not-`AnyRef`, and the rest should be caught by `AnyRef` as normal.

Comment: Is this behavior described in the Scala specification? I really wonder how the present behavior can be formalized in general.

Comment: @Blaisorblade - I'm not sure.  It's kind of an edge case.  I don't think there's anything to generalize _to_.

Comment: @RexKerr: Well, it won't generalize beyond `AnyVal` children, nor beyond permutations of the different cases. Anyway, I did look up in the spec, and neither Sec. 12.2, nor Sec. 8.1-8.2 hint at any such problem, so the first code fragment does not agree with the specification. But I fear the day when matching against `AnyRef` will work and filter out matches against `AnyVal`, given the performance cost. I think matches against `AnyRef` should trigger a warning or an error, suggesting to match against `Any`, especially since `AnyVal` is already forbidden.